Difference in meaning between singular and plural in negative statements
I want to figure out the differences between the following sentences and if they have the same meaning?
What about adding "any" in the middle.

I don't have a question. --- I don't have questions. --- I don't have any questions.
I don't have a car. --- I don't have cars. --- I don't have any cars.
I have no money. --- I don't have money. --- I don't have any money.


PLease add what research you have done. What don't you understand in the difference between asking about one item or more than one? What difference do you think adding "any" makes?

@peter Hello, thanks for your reply. Can I interpret "I don't have a question" as "I have more than one question?". Also "I don't have any questions" means I have only one questions? I don't have any questions means I have zero questions.

If you signal, in some manner (tone of voice, italics in text), that you are deliberately using the plural ("don't have questions") to mean "more than one question", or if you deliberately signal that you are using the indefinite article a ("a question") to mean "just one question", then those phrases can have different practical meaning in context.

I don't have questions.I have only one question. 
I don't have a question. I have more than one question.

But absent such signals, they would be understood to mean the same thing: you have nothing to ask.
